# Reduce data json HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, json, markup

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to hide the last 12 numbers on price in the button, as it is way to long.

I am using a JSON api, and insertAjacentHTML markup.

This is the code.

`

```
<script>
    fetch('https://free-api.vestige.fi/asset/467518794/price')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
       console.log(data.price);
         const markup = `<a>${data.price}</a>`;
         document.querySelector('button').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', markup);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
</script>
```

`

I tried a couple of different methods, but I am just not too great with json and javascript together.

Comment: how about `.substring(0, 8)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are built-in methods for numbers in javascript that can help you manipulate those values.

One of them is `.toFixed()`, it let's you take a number of digits after the decimal. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Here is an example:

```js
const number = 1254.211545
console.log(number.toFixed(4)) // result: 1254.2115
```

So in your case this code below should work:

```
<script>
    fetch('https://free-api.vestige.fi/asset/467518794/price')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
       console.log(data.price.toFixed(7));
         const markup = `<a>${data.price.toFixed(7)}</a>`;
         document.querySelector('button').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', markup);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
</script>
```

Or just, like @Teddy mentioned in the comments, there is also the `.substring()` method for strings, you need to convert you number to a string first to use it `.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try convert you number to string then use `substring`:

```
fetch("https://free-api.vestige.fi/asset/467518794/price")
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const numberToString = data.price.toString();
    const price = numberToString.substring(0, numberToString.length - 12);
    const markup = `<a>${price}</a>`;
    document.querySelector("button").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", markup);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```